# Is dielectric polarization a surface phenomenon?

Tags: polarization, dielectric

I know that in the presence of external electric field the dielectric material polarizes and the electron cloud is shifted towards the external charge (assuming the external charge is positive) but does that electron cloud shifting happens throughout the material or is it just happening on the surface of the dielectric?

Answer (score 2):

no , polarization in dielectric is throughout the medium [image]

but the net charge produced within bulk of material is $0$, so we consider only charges at surface (outside green box in above diagram)